# Rigging pupils and iris

Tags: rigging

I was wondering if there are any common ways/techniques on how to rig an eye's pupil and/or iris. I did some research on the internet, but couldn't find any tutorials. Each eye rig tutorial only covers how to create a look at target for eye balls.

Just to make sure you understand what I am talking about:
https://youtu.be/bTkmPqxWGMI?t=44

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: hello, what do you want to do with the iris and pupil? If you need to scale the pupil you could use shape keys

Comment: @moonboots like in the video provided I want to have contorl over the pupils and iris scale. But they should scale along the shape of a sphere/eye

Comment: so Shape Keys and Shrinkwrap seem like the way to go?

Comment: unless you need to export in a game engine or something?

Comment: it is for animation film purposes, so it can make use of any rigging techniques and tools provided by blender. how would you approach that using shape keys and shrinkwrap?

Comment: does your iris need to be concave like in your video?

Comment: preferably, yes

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 identical spheres. Make the first one invisible. For the second one, create the concave iris, give a vertex group to the whole eye except the iris, give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with the group you've just created as *Vertex Group* and the invisible sphere as *Target*. Also give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Go in the *Object Data* panel, create 2 shape keys, keep the second one selected, go in *Edit* mode, scale up the iris and move it a bit back. Here is what it should give:

[image]